# How can I get a button in Shiny to call both JavaScript and R code in parallel?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have an HTML button in Shiny that when clicked, calls the JavaScript function `geocodeAddressStreet(...)` in a `.js` file in the `/www` directory:

```
tags$body(tags$input(type = "button", 
                     value = "Next", 
                     id = "button1", 
                     onClick = "geocodeAddressStreet(houseNumber,streetName,addressCity,addressState)"))),
```

However I cannot figure out how to get this button to call a second file when clicked, let's say `foo.R`.  Both procedures run independently, but it seems like there's no way to add an `inputId` to an HTML element in Shiny.  We currently have two different buttons, one of which calls R code and the other of which calls JavaScript code, but this is clearly an impractical solution.

Comment: In `server.r` can't you just set up an `observe()` that will call the script when the button is clicked?

Comment: Don't you need an `inputId` though?  This button just has a standard HTML ID as far as I can tell.

Comment: What's wrong with the standard `actionButton` shiny function?

Comment: We couldn't get it to call the JavaScript code we needed, which is in a different file.

Comment: `actionButton("name","This is a Button",onClick="geoCodeAddressStreet")`

Answer (score 7):

So you want to have a button and when you click it, both a javascript function and some R code get called?  I was able to do this with the `onclick` function from the [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) package  (disclaimer: I wrote the package)

```
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- "
shinyjs.geocodeAddr = function(params) {
  alert('JavaScript called!');
  // geocodeAddressStreet(...)
}
"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
    actionButton("btn", "Click me")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    onclick("btn", {
      js$geocodeAddr()
      cat("R called as well")
    })
  }
))
```

Basically, the `onclick` function is an R function that will run when the button is clicked. Within it you can obviously call R code easily, but you can also call JS code using the shinyjs package -- that's how I made a call to `js$geocodeAddr`. Look at the `extendShinyjs` function. Alternatively, instead of using `extendShinyjs()`, you can also use the usual approach of `session$sendCustomMessage(...)`

Comment: Thanks!  I'm about to try this.  How can I do this while keeping the JavaScript in a separate file though?  Like instead of jsCode <- "(javaScript code)", so jsCode <- load(blah.js)

Comment: `extendShinyjs(script = "path/to/js")` instead of the `text` parameter. Hence my suggestion "Look at the `extendShinyjs` function -- read its documentation, it'll take 5 minutes, but might make your life easier :)(hopefully)