# Problem when reloading an animated GIF in Chrome

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I have an app that reloads an animated gif. It works all the time in Safari and intermittently in Chrome. I believe the problem is similar to one mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/9SB_uNg019M).

My knowledge of Javascript is negligible. However, reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346558/how-can-i-get-a-button-in-shiny-to-call-both-javascript-and-r-code-in-parallel), I came up with this example, which still doesn't work. Using Chrome, if you click again enough times you will see that sometimes the image reload fails.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- '
shinyjs.reset_anim = function() {
  var div_elem = document.getElementById("anim_plot");
  var img_elem = div_elem.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
  var src_value = img_elem.getAttribute("src");
  img_elem.setAttribute("src", "");
  img_elem.setAttribute("src", src_value);
}
'


# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
                extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),

                plotOutput("anim_plot",
                           width = "900px",
                           height = "200px"),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,  
                    actionButton("do_again", "Again")
                  )
                )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$do_again, {
    js$reset_anim()
    output$anim_plot <- renderImage({
      list(src = "www/tmp/ani.gif",
           contentType = 'image/gif',
           width = 900,
           alt = "Text"
      )
    }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can find an animated gif [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ll0six5rrxkn2b2/ani.gif?dl=0).

Comment: are you also using `V8`? I think that's highly recommended in the `shinyjs` documentation

Comment: I was not aware of V8 until you mentioned it. V8 - An R interface to Google's open source JavaScript engine.

Comment: so if you check `?shinyjs::extendShinyjs`, then you see it mentioned in the `Note` towards the bottom. It doesn't require an extra function call, you just need to have it available

Comment: I think the bigger issue is that my Javascript is incorrect or I am calling it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I avoid using renderImage for this kind of things. In the past I struggled with this function myself for a while (it's great for plots, but not for real png, jpeg, gif etc it seems) so here is a working alternative using html img() tag as renderUI output object. Seems your javascript works fine. Also, you can just use the online image, which I find works better than a locally stored one

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- '
shinyjs.reset_anim = function() {
  var div_elem = document.getElementById("anim_plot");
  var img_elem = div_elem.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
  var src_value = img_elem.getAttribute("src");
  img_elem.setAttribute("src", "");
  img_elem.setAttribute("src", src_value);
}
'


# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
                extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
                uiOutput('anim_plot'),
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,  
                         actionButton("do_again", "Again")
                  )
                )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$anim_plot <- renderUI({
    img(src='https://uc290691998b0891615b1f3e9397.previews.dropboxusercontent.com/p/orig/AAae6QYO7VLEEUVYdUuL985gwFGGVQ_RJ0mjLtfJt0bk3UO1ThezW4YO7R5LUzN9_m6moBjubhfX2AAnYmEkwDEjnwIw1gLOWUrOw4q_pKYYtXW-JCgghu4NuCgPKCm3RXxt3rNULvlUg-cP_Oj2vnItglJchP6a6a_lyApxTdZHwPk4Yv6jWxiYANVdFAVKxiTeHWVC5J3PYDeW8yOnaj4VGDj92eJCIXYtjpmznffo0tPUdUovNJMMW5nzsgT0L38w_5h39bcBxIwoCBmZ95iC8SRd9BGHxJMGCM4HUVh_Ly0VW3lwBxUx3O__VD5Ind-lahJwVkZjmet-HzP6XnUB/p.gif?size_mode=5', align = "right")
  })

  observeEvent(input$do_again, {
    js$reset_anim()

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE:**
App with server file, ui file and 5 gifs in the www folder: 
I just downloaded 5 random gifs from [giphy](http://giphy.com), and made one to not loop with [ezgif.com](https://ezgif.com/), stored them as gif1.gif, gif2.gif etc.

@OP: Keep in mind that your javascript targets 1 particular gif object. If you want to reload another gif, you would have to rewrite your javascript to take an input argument, which would be the name of your anim_plot n you wish to restart I guess. I'm no javascript expert, so I'm not going to attempt to add that here, but if you do, feel free to add it to the information here

p.s. 1: do not put 'www/' in your src argument. Shiny automatically looks inside the www folder. .

p.s 2: keep in mind that some things don't work in the internal interface of RStudio, and set it to run shiny apps externally by clicking "run external" under the tiny arrow menu that is on the right of the "Run App" play button.

```
# File of the server.
server <- function(input, output) {

  lapply(1:5, function(image_id) { 
  output[[paste('anim_plot', image_id, sep = '')]] <- renderUI({
    img(src=paste('gif', image_id, '.gif', sep = ''), align = "right")

    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$do_again, {
    js$reset_anim()

  })
}


# File of UI ----
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- '
shinyjs.reset_anim = function(anim_plot2) {
  var div_elem = document.getElementById("anim_plot2");
  var img_elem = div_elem.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
  var src_value = img_elem.getAttribute("src");
  img_elem.setAttribute("src", "");
  img_elem.setAttribute("src", src_value);
}
'


ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
                extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
                uiOutput('anim_plot1'),
                uiOutput('anim_plot2'),
                uiOutput('anim_plot3'),
                uiOutput('anim_plot4'),
                uiOutput('anim_plot5'),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,  
                         actionButton("do_again", "Again")
                  )
                )
)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am creating an animated gif and storing it locally. When I switch over to your renderUI approach it displays the first animated gif fine. However, it doesn't display the subsequent animated gifs even though I can see the file was created correctly. Is this issue related to your comment, "(external URLs) I find work better than a locally stored one"? Any thoughts on how to get local gifs working?

Comment: I propose you accept this answer, and then post a new question with the scenario you describe. I will have a look at it then and later today I will test this single gif for you with local storage. What do you mean with correctly created

Comment: Correctly created means that the file that is referenced here, img(src = 'tmp/ani.gif'), has been updated successfully.

Comment: Ah you mean rendered in the app I assume. Will you post a new question for the other part you asked for a scenario with more than 1 image?

Comment: I just made an app with 5 locally stored gifs, and they all render fine for me.. The code is in the update in my answer. p.s. I think you have to assign your bounty manually to be granted.

Comment: New question is now posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388079/problem-when-reloading-an-animated-gif-in-chrome-part-ii