# Problem when reloading an animated GIF in Chrome - Part II

Tags: javascript, r, google-chrome, shiny

Continuing from Mark's suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213748/problem-when-reloading-an-animated-gif-in-chrome/55364883?noredirect=1#comment97488676_55364883) I am now using `uiOutput` and `renderUI`.

The code below displays an animated gif ("anione"). When the "Again" button is pressed it resets Chrome with Javascript in ways that I don't fully understand and then simulates my larger program by overwriting the original animated gif with another animated gif ("anitwo").

However, "anitwo" is not displayed, "anione" is displayed. I can view the local file and see that it was written and view it successfully by opening it in Chrome. How do I view a different file of the same name?

I realize that I am inconsistent in my use of "www/tmp/ani.gif" and "tmp/ani.gif" and understand that shiny looks for files in "www". Yet, without these inconsistencies I get file not found errors.

ani.gif and ani2.gif are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i19zhzxrs18xgkz/ani_ani2.zip?dl=0).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(magick)

jsCode <- '
shinyjs.reset_anim = function() {
  var div_elem = document.getElementById("anim_plot");
  var img_elem = div_elem.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
  var src_value = img_elem.getAttribute("src");
  img_elem.setAttribute("src", "");
  img_elem.setAttribute("src", src_value);
}
'


# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
                extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
                uiOutput('anim_plot'),
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,  
                         actionButton("do_again", "Again")
                  )
                )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {


  output$anim_plot <- renderUI({
    img(src = 'tmp/ani.gif',
        width = '900')
  })

  observeEvent(input$do_again, {
    print("Again")
    js$reset_anim()

    # When Again clicked, simulate the creation of a new animated gif by reading in a file and 
    # over writing the old one. Try displaying this new animated gif.

    img2 <- image_read("www/tmp/ani2.gif")
    image_write(img2, path = "www/tmp/ani.gif")

    output$anim_plot <- renderUI({
      img(src = 'tmp/ani.gif',
          width = '900')
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I see that Stephane who often answers my own questions has posted a nice answer.  I am curious how you make GIFs in your app by the way, as I might have a use for that in my own program that i'm building.

Comment: The hard work is done by Thomas Lin Pedersen's transformr package: https://github.com/thomasp85/transformr. If you can get whatever shapes you wish to morph into a simple feature object (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf1.html) then transformr can generate an animated gif for you.

Comment: Ah that probably wont be suitable for making a gif of plots or pngs there of

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply do

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('anim_plot'),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,  
           actionButton("do_again", "Again")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  gif <- reactiveVal("ani.gif")

  observeEvent(input$do_again, {
    gif("ani2.gif")
  })

  output$anim_plot <- renderUI({
    img(src = gif(), width = "256")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: very elegant solution to not need javascript at all I would say Stéphane

Comment: I like the no Javascript. However, it does not work for me. I think the problem is that in my R script that does the letter morphing there is no ani2.gif. The script morphs symbols into a word that the user types in. The resulting animated gif is always stored as ani.gif. That is why in my example I am always displaying ani.gif. ani2.gif is just a stand-in for the next animated gif that gets created and is saved as ani.gif.

Comment: Is there a way to manually tell the "reactive value" object, "gif" that it has changed?